# input box not centering

Tags: html, css, doctype

For some reason, my website isn't centering an input box. Code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");

body { background-color: black; }

#textInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Digturd.io</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="textInput" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

The textbox I created is, for some reason, not centered into body. Is there any reason why?
Codepen: https://codepen.io/ARandomUncreativeName123/pen/oNqqeoY
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");

body { background-color: black; }

#textInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Digturd.io</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="textInput" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Just replace `right: 50%` to `left: 50%` and add transform.

```
#textInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this technique if it fits.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");

body { background-color: black; }

.center{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#textInput {
    position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Digturd.io</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <input id="textInput" type="text">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to center this in the body use `vh and vw` it will calculate using the width of the viewport, also set the height and width of the `html and body` tag using viewport height and width.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");

html, body { background-color: black; width:100vw; height:100vh; margin: 0; }

#textInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50vh;
    right: calc(50vw - 150px);
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Digturd.io</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="textInput" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
    <title>Digturd.io</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="textInput" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");

body { 
background-color: black;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

#textInput {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: calc(50% - 150px);
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way to center something horizontally is using the `text-align: center` property to the parent element.

```
<div class="textInputDiv">
   <input id="textInput" type="text">
</div>
```

And apply this css over it in which `text-align: center` property will ensure it's child is in center horizontally. And `position: absolute; top: 50%;` will center your input box vertically.

```
body { background-color: black; }

.textInputDiv{
   text-align: center;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
}
```